# Mysql not loading query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with an status and a time. The goal is to calculate the total time for each status.
Example Table:

| ID | or_id | status | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Ready | 10:45:33 |
| 2 | 1 | Production | 10:48:33 |
| 3 | 1 | material | 10:51:33 |
| 4 | 2 | material | 10:55:34 |
| 5 | 1 | Ready | 11:05:30 |
| 6 | 1 | Production | 11:08:38 |
| 7 | 2 | Production | 11:09:52 |

The plan is to select the previous status and timedifference. In table form for or_id =1:

| ID | or_id | status | time | prev_status | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Ready | 10:45:33 | null | null |
| 2 | 1 | Production | 10:48:33 | Ready | 180 |
| 3 | 1 | material | 10:51:33 | Production | 180 |
| 5 | 1 | Ready | 11:05:30 | material | 241 |
| 6 | 1 | Production | 11:08:38 | Ready | 188 |

The last step would be to group the status and sum the time diff, Result for or_id = 1:

| Status | Time |
| --- | --- |
| Ready | 368 |
| Production | 180 |
| Material | 241 |

For me the tables don't look correct in the final post while they do in the example so here is a picture:
[image]

```
CREATE TABLE orders_v 
    (
     orb_id int auto_increment primary key, 
     or_id int,
     or_production_status varchar(100), 
     or_create_date timestamp
    );

INSERT INTO orders_v
(orb_id, or_id, or_production_status, or_create_date)
VALUES
(1,1,'ready', '2021-06-07 10:45:33'),
(2,1,'production', '2021-06-07 10:48:33'),
(3,2,'ready', '2021-06-07 10:49:33'),
(4,1,'material', '2021-06-07 10:51:33'),
(5,1,'material', '2021-06-07 10:55:34'),
(6,1,'ready', '2021-06-07 11:05:30'),
(7,1,'production', '2021-06-07 11:08:38'),
(8,1,'ready', '2021-06-07 11:15:30')

SELECT
  (SELECT or_production_status FROM orders_v mt4
   WHERE mt4.or_id = 1
   AND mt4.orb_id < mt1.orb_id
   ORDER BY orb_id DESC LIMIT 1) as previous_name,
   SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,mt2.or_create_date,mt1.or_create_date)) AS Total   
FROM orders_v mt1
  LEFT JOIN orders_v mt2 ON mt2.or_create_date = (
    SELECT MAX(or_create_date)
    FROM orders_v mt3
    WHERE mt3.or_id = 1 AND (mt3.or_create_date < mt1.or_create_date))
WHERE mt1.or_id = 1
AND mt1.orb_id < (SELECT MAX(mt5.orb_id) FROM orders_v mt5)
GROUP BY previous_name
```

I got the following query and test setup: [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ddc0302/22)

This works reasonably. The problem is when I execute the query in MySql with more records, the query keeps loading like it is stuck in a loop without any error messages.

When breaking down the query in steps I can execute the query when deleting "AND (mt3.or_create_date < mt1.or_create_date))". But this gives out the incorrect result.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Use mysql 8.0 if possible. Then you can apply analytical function. Same table is used multiple time. this impacts performance.

Comment: So time represents when a status ended ? seems odd wouldn't you want to know when it started?

Comment: @P.Salmon The total time is used to calculate the efficiency. So in the example: 22% of the time the machine is in production, 47% the machine is ready for production(waste) and 31% of the time the machine is waiting for material (waste). The plan is to calculate the percentages in php.

Comment: I see the fiddle you have selected is for mysql 5.6 - is that what you are using?

Comment: @P.Salmon Yes, type: MySQL version: 5.6.26 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Comment: @RahulBiswas I tried to run the query in MariaDB 10.1.38 and it worked without any issue. I think the update is needed to solve this. Thanks.

Comment: Be very cautious comparing mysql to mariadb they are not the same..